# How to dynamically transfer data from the BoundService to the Activity?

Tags: java, android, service

The `BoundService` starts the counter from 0 to 100. It is necessary to receive the meter readings and dynamically change the `ProgressBar` in the `Activity`.

The code is exactly as Google recommends using the  `ServiceConnection`.

Comment: it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975440/communicate-from-service-to-activity-via-bound-service

Comment: Why the use of a service at all, if all it does is update the UI?

Comment: @MarkKeen I just want to figure out how this works to be ready to use it in the future, if needed.

Comment: @Badran thank u. Now I'll look.

Comment: "The code is exactly as Google recommends using the ServiceConnection." - erm, so you've implemented it as google recommends? You have lost me? Remember you've not posted any code here, we can only go on what you have written

Comment: you can opt for a LocalBroadcastManager.